# Laravel 5.6 TrustedProxies error

Tags: php, laravel, proxy, laravel-5.6

I've upgraded from L5.5 to L5.6 today (updating Symfony components to v4 in the process). Also I've updated `fideloper/proxy` package to 4.0 as of official Laravel 5.6 upgrade guide.

After that I starts to getting this error: `Type error: Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setTrustedProxies() must be of the type integer, array given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php on line 54`

Symfony 4's `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setTrustedProxies()` indeed expects integer (bitmask) as a 2nd argument:

```
/**
* Sets a list of trusted proxies.
*
* You should only list the reverse proxies that you manage directly.
*
* @param array $proxies          A list of trusted proxies
* @param int   $trustedHeaderSet A bit field of Request::HEADER_*, to set which headers to trust from your proxies
*
* @throws \InvalidArgumentException When $trustedHeaderSet is invalid
*/
public static function setTrustedProxies(array $proxies, int $trustedHeaderSet)
{
    self::$trustedProxies = $proxies;
    self::$trustedHeaderSet = $trustedHeaderSet;
}
```

and `fideloper/proxy` 4.0 is indeed gives an array instead of an integer into this function:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request::setTrustedProxies([], $this->getTrustedHeaderNames()); // Reset trusted proxies between requests
    $this->setTrustedProxyIpAddresses($request);
    return $next($request);
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Retrieve trusted header name(s), falling back to defaults if config not set.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getTrustedHeaderNames()
{
    return $this->headers ?: $this->config->get('trustedproxy.headers');
}
```

So I can't understand if this is bug in `fideloper/proxy` or I'm just missing something?

Comment: Same here. Project upgraded from Laravel 5.5 to 5.6, running vagrant homestead. Tried deleting vendor directory and running `composer install` again- same issue. Please post any solution.

Comment: Stupid thing is: It's mentioned in the upgrade guide, but near the end. I scrolled through it expecting the most important change to be first, but no, the one that actually breaks your webinterface is near the end :)

Comment: Did the same thing :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated in [the upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade), you need to set the $headers property in *App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies* to a bit property.

The constants are defined in *Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request*.

```
const HEADER_FORWARDED = 0b00001; // When using RFC 7239
const HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR = 0b00010;
const HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST = 0b00100;
const HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO = 0b01000;
const HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT = 0b10000;
const HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL = 0b11110; // All "X-Forwarded-*" headers
const HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB = 0b11010; // AWS ELB doesn't send X-Forwarded-Host
```

In the upgrade guide, HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL is used but you can use a combination of the bit values.

Answer (score 33):

After some investigation (Winmerge comparison with a fresh install of Laravel 5.6) this comes down to a difference in the files `app\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php`:

**Laravel 5.5:**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies;

    /**
     * The current proxy header mappings.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $headers = [
        Request::HEADER_FORWARDED => 'FORWARDED',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
    ];
}
```

**Laravel 5.6:**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies;

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

**Ergo, set `protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;` as per Laravel 5.6 version**

Answer (score 23):

Open `app\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php`.

**Change the following**

```
protected $headers = [
    Request::HEADER_FORWARDED => 'FORWARDED',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
];
```

**to**

```
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
```

Comment: Useful from Laravel 5.6 up, I'm on Laravel 5.8 also helpful. Good luck and happy new year of 2021!

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind also that when upgrading from Laravel 5.5 to 5.6 Laravel creates a new file called TrustProxies.php with the same namespace as TrustedProxies i.e `"App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies"`.  In Laravel 5.6, the `TrustedProxies.php` file is **correct** as mentioned above.
The `TrustProxies.php` is not.  But if they both exist in the same namespace, then Laravel will use the one that it finds first, and that is the `TrustProxies.php` file.

If you have both, then delete `TrustProxies.php`, and make sure that `TrustedProxies.php` has the correct changes as mentioned above.

Have an awesome day. 
Christian

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue in Laravel 9.x or later, it is because Laravel has [incorporated the package into the core framework](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy/issues/152) and it's no longer needed.

The [fideloper/TrustedProxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy/) repo has added a note to it's readme instructing not to install the package on Laravel 9.x and instead follow the [Laravel upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#the-assert-deleted-method).

You can find the upgrade notes in the Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#the-assert-deleted-method) under the heading "Trusted Proxies".

I found the change in the upgrade guide took me all of 30 seconds to complete!